# How to upload a repeated property into ndb datastore with appcfg.py

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, bulkloader

I've been using appcfg.py to upload_data pretty successfully, but I'm not sure how to set up the import transform in `bulkloader.yaml` for repeated properties or how to structure the CSV. For example:

In a post model that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

and a `bulkloader.yaml` looks like this:

```
transformers:
- kind: Post
  connector: csv

  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
    - property: tags
      external_name: tags
      import_transform: ???
```

is `import_transform` the right API to register for this? Or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a two step approach that seems to work using the import_transform.  First create a module (essentially a custom transform file), let's say bulkmodify.py.  Then in bulkmodify define a transform converting the incoming value to a list

```
def list_convert(value):
    output=[value]
    return output
```

Then in your `bulkloader.yaml` file specify the import transform for your repeated property:

```
import_transform: bulkmodify.list_convert
```

Also don't forget to include your module in the import list at the top of your `bulkloader.yaml` file.

`- import: bulkmodify`

In my input CSV the data is structured with multiple quotes so the bulkloader brings them in as a single property with multiple listed values

```
key,"""tag1"",""tag2"",""tag3""", property3, etc.
```

Comment: I'll try that. I wasn't sure how to write my transform function, but I'll check it out.